# Compute $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(2+\cos\theta)^2}\,d\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I''m stuck in a exercise in complex analysis concerning integration of rational trigonometric functions. Here it goes:

We want to evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(2+\cos\theta)^2}\,d\theta$.

Here's my work:

Let $z=e^{i\theta}$ so that $d\theta=dz/iz$ and $\cos \theta = \frac12 (z+z^{-1})$.  We have

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(2+\cos\theta)^2}\,d\theta \quad (1)\\\\ 
&=\oint_C \frac{1}{(2+\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2})^2}\frac{dz}{iz} \quad (2)\\\\ 
&=\frac1i\oint_C \frac{4}{(4+z+z^{-1})^2}\frac{dz}{z} \quad (3) \\\\ 
&=\frac4i\oint_C \frac{1}{(z^2+4z+1)^2}\,dz \quad (4) \\\\ 
&=\frac4i\oint_C \frac{1}{(z-(-2+\sqrt3)^2(z-(-2-\sqrt3)^2}\,dz \quad (5)\\\\
&=\frac4i\oint_Cf(z)\,dz \quad (6)
\end{align}$$

where $C$ is the unit circle in the complex $z$-plane.

The function $f(z)$ has singularities at $(-2\pm\sqrt3)$ but only $(-2+\sqrt3)\in int(C)$. Therefore,

$$\oint_Cf(z)\,dz=2\pi i (Res(f, (-2+\sqrt3))) \quad (*)$$

Since $(-2+\sqrt3)$ is a pole of order $2$, after a quick calculation I get

$$Res(f, (-2+\sqrt3)=-\frac{\sqrt3}{3}$$

and so for $(*)$ I get

$$\oint_Cf(z)\,dz=2\pi i (-\frac{\sqrt3}{3})=-\frac{2\pi\sqrt3i}{3}.$$

Hence, by $(6)$, I find

$$\frac4i\oint_Cf(z)\,dz=\frac4i \left(\frac{-2\pi\sqrt3i}{3}\right)=-\frac{8\pi\sqrt3}{3}.$$

---

My solution however is not correct. The given integral evaluates to $\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt3}$ (verified with Wolfram). I suspect there must be a flaw in one of my steps from $(1)$ to $(6)$ but I can't find it.

Comment: The mistake is between 3 and 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $(4)$ is $$\frac{4}{i}
 \oint_{C}\frac{\color{red}{z}}{\left(z^{2}+4z+1\right)^{2}}dz
 $$ and $$\textrm{Res}_{z=-2+\sqrt{3}}\left(\frac{z}{\left(z^{2}+4z+1\right)^{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{6\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: I don't understand why do we get a $z$ in the numerator of the integrand. I just factor the $z$ inside the square but I don't see why this is wrong. Would you mind explain this?

Comment: @ManonVd $$\frac{4}{i}\oint_{C}\frac{1}{(4+z+z^{-1})^{2}}\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{4}{i}\oint_{C}\frac{1}{(\frac{z^{2}+4z+1}{z})^{2}}\frac{dz}{z}$$ let me know if I have to add more details.

Comment: No need to add more details, it's perfectly clear now. Thank you Marco.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a+\cos x}dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{1}{a-\cos x}dx=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{a-\cos x}dx$$
We know $\cos x=\large \frac{1-\tan^2\frac x 2}{{1-\tan^2\frac x 2}}$,thus
$$I(a)=2\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{{1+\tan^2\frac x 2}}{(a-1)+(a+1)\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}dx=\frac{2}{(a+1)}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1+\tan^2\frac x 2}{\frac{a-1}{a+1}+\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}dx$$
set $u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$, we have
$$I(a)=\frac{4}{a+1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\frac{a-1}{a+1}+u^2}du=\frac{4}{a+1}\sqrt{\frac{a+1}{a-1}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a+1}{a-1}u\right)\large|_{0}^{\infty}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$

> $$I(a)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{a+\cos x}dx=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-1}}$$

$$I'(a)=-\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(a+\cos x)^2}dx=-\frac{2\pi a}{(a^2-1)^\frac32}$$
In the other words

> $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(a+\cos x)^2}dx=\frac{2\pi
>  a}{(a^2-1)^\frac32}$$

now set $a=2$

Comment: "I suspect there must be a flaw in one of my steps from (1) to (6) but I can't find it." How do you address this? (Not to mention that the reason why the $2\pi/\sqrt{a^2-1}$ formula holds, might be far from obvious to this OP.)

Comment: @ Mr Did I will edit it

Comment: Another option is to see that another user addressed the question hence the present answer can be deleted (unless you introduce another method) and you might want to concentrate more, in the future, on what the posters are really asking.

Comment: Do you have access to who votes what? If you do not, what allows you to speculate on that and to formulate public accusations? And do you think each of your answers is perfect? More productive would be "to concentrate more, in the future, on what the posters are really asking". For example the present answer still does not in the least address the OP's question. Why is that?