# Definite integral on $[0,\pi]$

Tags: integration

How to calculate the following integral if $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$:
$$\int \limits_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\varphi}{(1+\varepsilon\cos \varphi)^2}$$

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846774/how-to-evaluate-int-02-pi-frac11a-cos-theta2-d-theta-without-c

Comment: this says WA$$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\log \left(\frac{1-\epsilon }{\sqrt{\epsilon
   ^2-1}}\right)-\log \left(\frac{\epsilon -1}{\sqrt{\epsilon ^2-1}}\right)}{\left(\epsilon
   ^2-1\right)^{3/2}},\left(\Re\left(\sec ^{-1}(\epsilon )\right)<0\lor \Re\left(\sec
   ^{-1}(-\epsilon )\right)<0\lor \csc ^{-1}(\epsilon )\notin \mathbb{R}\right)\land
   ((\Re(\epsilon )+1>0\land \Re(\epsilon )<1\land \Re(\epsilon )\neq 0)\lor \epsilon \notin
   \mathbb{R})\right]$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(1+a\cos {\theta})^2}\,d\theta$ without contour integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1846774/how-to-evaluate-int-02-pi-frac11a-cos-theta2-d-theta-without-c)

Comment: Can you recognize the area enclosed by an ellipse?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Use the substitution
$$
s=\tan{\frac{\varphi}{2}}, \quad \sin{\varphi}=\frac{2s}{s^2+1}, \quad \cos{\varphi} = \frac{1-s^2}{s^2+1}.
$$

(Apparently more details are given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124227/58780).)

Comment: You mean to make substitution $\varphi=\tan \frac{t}{2}$?

Comment: @RFZ: No, it would be (as in my answer) $s=2\arctan{\varphi}$.

Comment: I have applied trigonometric substitution and I have got the following integral $\int \limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(1+u^2)du}{(1+u^2+\varepsilon-\varepsilon u^2)^2}$ and I stuck

Comment: @RFZ: You're missing a factor two in the numerator, but otherwise it looks good. Next thing to do is bring the denominator to the form $(1+v^2)^2$. Do you see what substitution accomplishes this (there are two)?

Answer (score 1):

Complex analysis approach: by letting $z=e^{i\varphi}$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{d\varphi}{(1+\varepsilon\cos \varphi)^2}&=
\frac{1}{2}\int \limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{d\varphi}{(1+\varepsilon\cos \varphi)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int \limits_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{(1+\varepsilon(z+1/z)/2)^2}\cdot \frac{dz}{iz}\\
&=\frac{2}{i}\int \limits_{|z|=1}\frac{z}{(\varepsilon z^2+2z+\varepsilon)^2}\,dz\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{\varepsilon^2}\,\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{z}{ (z-w_+)^2(z-w_-)^2},w_+
\right)\\
&=\frac{\pi}{(1-\varepsilon^2)^{3/2}}.
\end{align*}
where $\displaystyle w_{\pm}=\frac{\pm\sqrt{1-\varepsilon^2}-1}{\varepsilon}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{d\varphi}{(1+\varepsilon\cos\varphi)^2} = -\frac{1}{(1-\varepsilon^2)}\Bigg[\frac{\varepsilon\sin\varphi}{1+\varepsilon\cos\varphi}-\int \frac{d\varphi}{1+\varepsilon\cos\varphi}\Bigg]$$

Table of Integrals, Series, And Products 7th ed 2.554.3

Comment: Your integral does not correspond to the one in the question. The entire denominator should be squared, not just the cosine.

Comment: Sorry, it should be fixed.