# How to integrate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1-a\cos x)^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, trigonometric-integrals

I'm having a hard time trying to resolve this integral :
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1-a\cos x)^2}$$
where $a$ is a positive real constant.

I tried using substitution, but I'm stuck by the fact that the integral must be computed between $0$ and $2\pi$, which leads to integration between $X$ and $X$ (where $X$ can be $0$ or $1$ anything following the substitution in the boundaries).
I'm not looking for the full result if the computation is complicated, just some lead to start off...

Thanks

UPDATE : seeing the answers proposed, I checked that indeed $|a|<1$.

Comment: Do you realize it essentially is the area enclosed by an ellipse?

Comment: Similar : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1846774/321264.

Comment: You can start with the standard result $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{a-b\cos x} =\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{a^2-b^2}}$$ and differentiate it with respect to $a$ and then put $a=1$ and replace $b$ by $a$.

Answer (score 14):

The polar equation of an ellipse (with respect to a focus, taking the aphelion as the point associated to $\theta=0$) is
$$ \rho(\theta) = \frac{\ell}{1-e\cos\theta} $$
where, in terms of the standard parameters, $\ell$ is the semi-latus rectum $\frac{b^2}{a}$ and $e$ is the eccentricity $\frac{c}{a}$.
The area enclosed by such ellipse is $\pi a b $ or
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\ell^2}{(1-e\cos\theta)^2}\,d\theta, $$
so we get that for any $e\in[0,1)$ the following identity holds:
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(1-e\cos\theta)^2}= \frac{2\pi a b}{\ell^2}=2\pi\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^3=\frac{2\pi}{\left(\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)^{3/2}}={\frac{2\pi}{(1-e^2)^{3/2}}}. $$
The same holds if, in the LHS, we replace $e$ with $-e$, since $ \rho(\theta) = \frac{\ell}{1+e\cos\theta} $ is the polar equation of the same ellipse, with the perihelion being taken as the point associated to $\theta=0$. So we get that for any $a\in(-1,1)$
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{(1-a\cos\theta)^2}= \color{blue}{\frac{2\pi}{(1-a^2)^{3/2}}}. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I did not realized this was the polar equation of an ellipse! This solution looks quite elegant. I also update my post, the coefficient $a$ is indeed always less than 1.

Comment: +1 for polar equation of ellipse. Although I believe computation of area of ellipse is easier if one uses rectangular coordinates. So in effect your answer uses the equivalence/transformation between these coordinate systems.

Answer (score 4):

**HINT:**

Note that for $|a|<1$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(1-a\cos(\theta))^2}\,d\theta&=\frac1{a^2}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(1/a-\cos(\theta))^2}\,d\theta\\\\
&=-\frac1{a^2}\frac{d}{d(1/a)}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1/a-\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\tag1\\\\
&= -\frac2{a^2}\frac{d}{d(1/a)}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{1/a-\cos(\theta)}\,d\theta\tag2
\end{align}$$

Now use the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) to evaluate the integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ and differentiate to obtain the coveted result.

Alternatively, one could use contour integration to evaluate the integral of interest or evaluate the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$.

Comment: The Weierstrass substitution is going to fail if you apply it to this integral. You have to do something first (integrate on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and split, for instance).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut This was meant to be a HINT only.  But I've added another line to facilitate.

Answer (score 4):

My goal with this answer is to give you a bunch of different really general integral formulas that you may find very useful.

$$F(a)=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+a\cos x)^2}$$
So your integral is $2F(-a)$. First off we will preform the tangent-half-angle substitution $t=\tan(x/2)$. Hence we have that 
$$F(a)=2\int_0^\infty \frac1{(1+a\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2})^2}\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^2}$$
$$F(a)=2\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1+t^2}{[(1-a)t^2+a+1]^2}\mathrm dt$$
Which we can rewrite as 
$$F(a)=\frac2{1-a}\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm dt}{(1-a)t^2+a+1}+\frac{4a}{a-1}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dt}{[(1-a)t^2+a+1]^2}$$

---

Next we consider the very general integral 
$$I(m;a,b)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{(ax^2+b)^{m+1}}$$
First we integrate by parts with $\mathrm dv=\mathrm dx$ to produce 
$$I(m;a,b)=\frac{x}{(ax^2+b)^{m+1}}\bigg|_0^{\infty}+2(m+1)\int_0^\infty\frac{ax^2}{(ax^2+b)^{m+2}}\mathrm dx$$
$$I(m;a,b)=2(m+1)\int_0^\infty\frac{ax^2+b-b}{(ax^2+b)^{m+2}}\mathrm dx$$
$$I(m;a,b)=2(m+1)I(m;a,b)-2(m+1)bI(m+1;a,b)$$
Then solving for $I(m+1;a,b)$ and replacing $m+1$ with $m$,
$$I(m;a,b)=\frac{2m-1}{2bm}I(m-1;a,b)$$
And for the base case:
$$I(0;a,b)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm dx}{ax^2+b}$$
The Trig sub $x=\sqrt{\frac{b}a}\tan u$ gives 
$$I(0;a,b)=\frac\pi{2\sqrt{ab}}$$
Which is a special case of 
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\frac{\mathrm dx}{ax^2+bx+c}=\frac2{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\arctan\frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\bigg|_{x_1}^{x_2}$$
Anyway, the recurrence has the solution 
$$I(m;a,b)=\frac\pi{2^{2m+1}b^m\sqrt{ab}}{2m\choose m}$$
Which we will apply very shortly!

---

Recalling the definition of $I(m;a,b)$, we have that 
$$F(a)=\frac2{1-a}I(0;1-a,1+a)+\frac{4a}{a-1}I(1;1-a,1+a)$$
$$F(a)=\frac\pi{(1-a^2)^{3/2}}$$
And since your integral is given by $2F(-a)$,
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm dx}{(1-a\cos x)^2}=\frac{2\pi}{(1-a^2)^{3/2}}$$

---

**ADDENDUM**

Consider the integral 
$$C(n;a)=\int_0^\pi \frac{\mathrm dx}{(1+a\cos x)^n}$$
Starting with $t=\tan\frac{x}2$,
$$C(n;a)=2\int_0^\infty \frac1{\left[1+a\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right]^n}\frac{\mathrm dt}{1+t^2}$$
$$C(n;a)=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\left(t^2+1\right)^{n-1}}{\left[(1-a)t^2+1+a\right]^n}\mathrm dt$$
Then using the binomial theorem,
$$C(n;a)=2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{\left[(1-a)x^2+1+a\right]^n}\mathrm dx$$
$$C(n;a)=\frac2{(1-a)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{\left[x^2+\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right]^n}\mathrm dx$$
We then recall the integral due to my collaborator [@DavidG](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/150203/davidg), 
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{q}}{\left[x^w+b\right]^p}\mathrm dx=\frac{b^{\frac{1+q}{w}-p}}{w}\frac{\Gamma\left(p-\frac{1+q}{w}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1+q}{w}\right)}{\Gamma\left(p\right)}$$
Here $\Gamma(s)$ is the Gamma function. So with $w=2$, $b=\frac{1+a}{1-a}$, $p=n$, and $q=2k$,
$$C(n;a)=\frac1{(1-a)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n-1\choose k}\left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)^{\frac{2k+1}{2}-n}\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(n\right)}$$
$$C(n;a)=\frac1{(1-a)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1+a}{1-a}\right)^{\frac{2k+1}{2}-n}\frac{\Gamma\left(n-\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{2k+1}{2}\right)}{k!\Gamma(n-k)}$$

Answer (score 1):

By symmetry, we have
$$
\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d x}{(1-a \cos x)^2}=2 \int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{(1-a \cos x)^2}
$$
Letting $x\mapsto \pi-x$ gives the other form of the integral
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{1-a\cos x}=
\int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{1+a\cos x}
$$
Averaging them yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{1-a \cos x}=&\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi\left(\frac{1}{1-a \cos x}+\frac{1}{1+a\cos x}\right) \\
= & \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{1-a^2 \cos ^2 x} d x \\
= & 2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sec ^2 x}{\sec ^2 x-a^2} d x \\
= & 2 \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d t}{t^2+\left(1-a^2\right)}, \quad \textrm{ where }t=\tan x \\
= & \frac{2}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\right)\right]_0^{\infty}  
\end{aligned} 
$$
$$\therefore \int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{1-a \cos x}=  \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \tag*{(*)}  $$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
\int_0^\pi \frac{\cos x}{(1-a \cos x)^2} d x= \frac{\pi a}{\left(1-a^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\tag*{(**)} 
$$
Noticing that
$$
\begin{aligned}
a \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos x}{(1-a \cos x)^2} d x & =\int_0^\pi \frac{1-(1-a \cos x)}{(1-a \cos x)^2} d x \\
& =\int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{(1-a\cos x)^2} d x-\int_0^\pi \frac{d x}{1-a \cos x}
\end{aligned}
$$
Combining $(*)$ and $(**)$ gives
$$
\int_0^{\pi} \frac{d x}{(1-a \cos x)^2}=\frac{ \pi}{\left(1-a^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
$$

Hence for any $|a|<1,$
$$
\boxed{\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d x}{(1-a \cos x)^2}=\frac{2 \pi}{\left(1-a^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}}
$$

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I added a line break to get the `\boxed` portion at the end to display properly :)