# How to integrate $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(k\cos\theta + 1)^2} d\theta$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I have the following identity in a derivation I'm trying to understand:

$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(k\cos\theta + 1)^2} d\theta = \frac{2\pi}{(1-k^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$

and I cannot see how this is true.  I'm sure it is - I just can't figure out how to integrate the LHS.  I've tried using tangent half-angle substitution, and although that gave me something I could integrate, the definite integral ended up being $0 - 0 = 0$, which wasn't entirely helpful...

Can anyone help?

Comment: It should be $-1<k<1.$ Otherwise the integral diverges.

Comment: Have you checked this posting? [How to evaluate $\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(1+a\cos {\theta})^2}\,d\theta$ without contour integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1846774/9340)

Comment: @SangchulLee No, I hadn't seen that - and it wasn't presented as a similar question.  But it does answer my question - thanks.